# mono rises unexpected compiler errors

Tags: mono, compiler-errors

I have the following class

```
public class LockRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public bool Ok { get; set; }        

    public LockRequest ( int id, string t)
    { 
        Id = id;
        TypeName = t;
    }
}
```

Then, it's referenced in a delegate, as follows

```
private static void ReceiveLockRequest<LockRequest>(PacketHeader header, Connection   connection, LockRequest input )
{
    LockRequest lr = new LockRequest(1, "SomeTypeName" );

    Console.WriteLine( String.Format ( "{0} ", input.TypeName) ); 
}
```

When compiling, both lines from the delegate rises compiler errors. 
The line with the "new()", produces "Cannot create an instance of the type class 'LockRequest' because it does not have the 'new()' constraint.
The line which would show some of the input data gives "The type 'Lockrequest' does not contains a definition for 'TypeName' and no extension method 'TypeName' ... etc".

Could someone explain why is this behaviour?

My dev environment is Ubuntu 10.04 (64 bits) and Monodevelop 2.8.6.3

TIA

Could add some info.

I changed the name of the class, and the thing compiled. The whole class is to be serialised by ProtoBuf, so it must be decorated with attributes. Here are is a sample

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo
{
   [ProtoMember(1)]
   public int  { get; protected set; }

   [ProtoMember(2)]
   public string TypeName { get; protected set; }

   ...
```

Just after I added the attributes, mono stop compiling. Same erors raise again.
To test it, I commented the attributes, do a Clean All, an recompile. The errors raise again, as if MonoDevelop cached them.

I need some help more than after the initial post.

2013-10-31

Thank you, Jester. It´s an event handler, from NetworkCommDotNet library.

My faults:

1) The first error (members not recognized) raises from the fact that (somewhat astobishing) the "input" argument comes as a plain object. Casting it in another method does the trick.
2) The error regarding the instanciation: the delegate definition in the library have a where clause wich states that T must be class, but no the new() constraint.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a delegate, that's a generic method.
It's not clear what you want to do and why do you need a generic method.
If you really do, then try something along the lines of:

```
private static void ReceiveLockRequest<T>(PacketHeader header, Connection   connection, T input) where T:LockRequest
```

PS: your development environment is very old, consider upgrading.